# Translate boolean to bool after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

**Hi,**

I have a .net class that contains a Boolean, this class is sent to client with AJAX. The problem is that if I just use :

```
if(MyClass.CheckedValue)
```

It will always be true even if the CheckedValue is false. I supose that it is instead checking if the object is set and if so it is true? Im note sure what type this Boolean propertie gets when returning to the javascript after AJAX?

I have also tried this :

```
var checked;
checked = Boolean(this.CheckedValue === 'true');

if (checked)
```

But this will also laways be true?

**How do I handle this?**

Edit1 :

The classes that is sent to client :

```
/// <summary>
/// Are set to client with Ajax to render a correct view of the
/// current category and filter settings
/// </summary>
public class GetCategoriesAndFiltersAjax
{

    public GetCategoriesAndFiltersAjax()
    {
        Filters = new Filter();
    }

    public SelectList categoryList { get; set; }
    public Filter Filters { get; set; }

    public class Filter
    {
        public Filter()
        {
            DefaultFilters = new List<CategoryItemFilter>();
            FilterList = new List<CategoryItemFilter>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Filters like buy, sell, let and so on
        /// </summary>
        public List<CategoryItemFilter> DefaultFilters { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// All other filters that a category might be bound to
        /// </summary>
        public List<CategoryItemFilter> FilterList { get; set; }
    }
}


public class CategoryItemFilter
{
    private int _filterId = -1;

    private string _clientElementId1;
    private string _clientElementId2;

    public FilterControlType FilterControlType { get; set; }
    public string Title1 { get; set; }
    public string Title2 { get; set; }
    public string ClientElementId1
    {
        get { return _clientElementId1; }
        set
        {
            _clientElementId1 = value;
        }
    }
    public string ClientElementId2
    {
        get { return _clientElementId2; }
        set
        {
            _clientElementId2 = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Keep track of whitch filter it is
    /// </summary>
    public int FilterId
    {
        get { return _filterId; }
        set { _filterId = value; }
    }

    #region Values
    public Boolean CheckedValue { get; set; }
    public string TextValue { get; set; }

    public SelectList DropDownList1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList DropDownList2 { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public PublicAdFilterKey PublicAdFilterKey { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how the AJAX method looks like on server :

```
public JsonResult GetCategoriesByParent(int id, Boolean editMode)
{
    FilterModel filterModel = new FilterModel();
    CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
    List<ModelViewCategory> mvCategoryList = new List<ModelViewCategory>();
    //List<AdCategory> categoryList;
    FilterHandler filterHandler = new FilterHandler();

    GetCategoriesAndFiltersAjax value = new GetCategoriesAndFiltersAjax();
    try
    {

        value.categoryList = new SelectList(categoryModel.GetCategoriesByParent(id).ToArray(), "Id", "Name");

        if (editMode)
            value.Filters = filterHandler.ConvertFilterModelToAjaxCategoryFilter(filterModel.GetCategoryFilterByCategory(id), Biss.Views.ViewClasses.Filter.FilterType.Edit);
        else
            value.Filters = filterHandler.ConvertFilterModelToAjaxCategoryFilter(filterModel.GetCategoryFilterByCategory(id), Biss.Views.ViewClasses.Filter.FilterType.Display);

        return this.Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Edit 2 :

This is how the client looks like(not exacly but close, its alot more complicated)

```
$.ajax({
                            url: actionPath,
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: ((typeof config.postData == "function") ? config.postData() : config.postData) || { id: $(source).val(), editMode: _filterInEditMode },
                            success: function (data) {
                                methods.reset();
                                $.each(data.categoryList, function () {
                                    SetFilterSubEdit(data.DefaultFilters);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                methods.showError();
                            }
                        });


function SetFilterSubEdit(data) {
    $.each(data, function () {
       if (data.CheckedValue)
                    $("#" + visibleElements[0]).attr('checked', checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your boolean is really false, why would `MyClass.CheckedValue` always evaluate to true?

Comment: Please post how `MyClass` is created on the client side. If it is parsed from JSON, please post the JSON as well. What is the exact value of `MyClass.CheckedValue` (`console.log(MyClass.CheckedValue)`)?

Comment: @James: If it is an instance of `Boolean` (i.e. not a `boolean`) then it is an object and objects always evaluate to true.

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks. I was thinking `boolean` not `Boolean`.

Comment: @James: Of course it might also be that `MyClass.CheckedValue` is neither `Boolean` nor `boolean` but just another value which always evaluates to `true`. We need more information here.

Comment: I have no updated the post with more info, is there somthing more you need to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was that the brackets was missing on client side.

```
if (data.CheckedValue){
}
```